# Merging multiple data frames in a list to another data frame by various columns

Tags: r

In my code I have used multiple `left_join` to merge separate data frames to the one I am working on in a dplyr chain. I imported the data frames I wanted to merge with the other one into a list, then did some manipulations directly on that list with lapply to prepare them for merging.

As of now, I have used `list2env(list, envir = .GlobalEnv)` to create separate data frames from the list, then used `left_join` to merge each one separately, by unique columns for each data frame, like this:

Test data:

List:

```
structure(list(df2 = structure(list(x = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), a = c(-0.331543943439452, 
0.0588350184156617, 1.03657229544754)), .Names = c("x", "a"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame"), df3 = structure(list(z = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("K", "L", "M"), class = "factor"), b = c(-0.897094152848114, 
0.97612075490695, 0.650264147064918)), .Names = c("z", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("df2", "df3"))
```

To create separate data frames:

```
list2env(testlist, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Data frame:

```
structure(list(x = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    y = 1:3, z = structure(1:3, .Label = c("K", "L", "M"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

To join:

```
library(dplyr)

test_df %>%
    left_join(., df2, by = "x") %>%
    left_join(., df3, by = "z")
```

**(Note that my list has around eight data frames with 2 - 3 columns each. I included only two data frames in this list for simplicity)**

All the data frames have their own individual "by" column. **What I want to know is if there is a simpler way to do this, f. ex by merging with the whole list directly, and automatically detecting which columns are similar and merging by them for each data frame instead of doing left_join eight separate times?**

**EDIT**

I tried running the following code, as suggested by @akrun:

```
out <- test
for(i in seq_along(table_list)) {
  nm1 <- intersect(names(out), names(table_list[[i]]))
  out <- merge(out, table_list[[i]], by = nm1)
}
out
```

Where `test` is the data frame to merge to, and `table_list` is the list of data frames.
This works for these small test data frames, but seem to introduce duplication of individual rows in the data frame, resulting in more rows.

More complex example data frame:

```
structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), y = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), z = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("K", "L", "M"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I have a doubt, do you 'n' number of `by` columns that is based on the number of elements in the `list`.  I meant that for your 8 data.frame list

Comment: Perhaps `out<- test_df;nm1 <- c("x", "z"); for(i in seq_along(nm1)) out <- merge(out, testlist[[i]], by = nm1[i], all.x= TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun not quite sure what you meant, but each of my data frames in the list is named with unique names, and they are of varying lengths.

Comment: Could you make the reproducible example a bit more complex so that it gives duplicates on the for loop code.  I can't test it without an example that shows the problem\

Comment: I also added `all.x = TRUE` in the `merge`

Comment: @akrun updated data frame added

Comment: With the new dataset, I get 8 rows as output just like the `left_join` output\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the complicated test_df, why not use `reduce` from `purrr` together with left_join from dplyr? I have included the messages and warning message in the code below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

all_dfs <- reduce(my_list, left_join, .init = test_df)

# (warning) messages from using left_join
# Joining, by = "x"
# Joining, by = "z"
# Warning message:
# Column `x` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector 

all_dfs

  x y z           a          b
1 A 1 K  0.05883502  0.6502641
2 B 2 L -0.33154394  0.9761208
3 C 3 M  1.03657230 -0.8970942
4 D 4 K          NA  0.6502641
5 A 1 L  0.05883502  0.9761208
6 B 2 M -0.33154394 -0.8970942
7 C 3 K  1.03657230  0.6502641
8 D 4 L          NA  0.9761208
```

Comment: Simple and brilliant - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, it seems that we need to check for intersecting column names before each `merge`

```
out <- test_df
for(i in seq_along(testlist)) {
   nm1 <- intersect(names(test_df), names(testlist[[i]]))
   out <- merge(out, testlist[[i]], by = nm1, all.x = TRUE)
 }

out
#  z x y           a          b
#1 K A 1  0.05883502  0.6502641
#2 L B 2 -0.33154394  0.9761208
#3 M C 3  1.03657230 -0.8970942
```

Comment: This seems to work, however my own data frame goes from 853 rows to 2760. This shouldn't add more rows, no?

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this with dplyr? I was hoping to include it in my chain

Comment: @Haakonkas  That could be because of duplicate ids for the merging columns.  Have you tried it using the way you showed\

Comment: @Haakonkas  Can you try with the change from `intersect(names(test_df),` to `intersect(names(out),`

Comment: I still get the same result, additional rows created. I have checked for duplicates in the data frame, but there are none. However, duplicates are produced when i run the above

Comment: @Haakonkas Suppose, if you run the code by the way you showed, do you get duplicates

Comment: I do not get duplicates with the left_join

Comment: Can you update the full code that you ran, just wanted to know whether you used column names differently.  The `for` loop code is also based on the same logic